# Qt, Make fails when I add a second source file

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, gnu-make

I have a *lessons* directory. At first glance, there is only one source file hello.cc in this directory.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel hello("<center>Welcome to my first Qt program</center>");
    hello.setWindowTitle("My First Qt Program");
    hello.resize(400, 400);
    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Also there is a Makefile in this directory which looks like this :

```
OPT := "QT += gui widgets"
SRC := $(shell ls -tp *.cc | grep -v /$ | head -1)
PRG = $(basename $(SRC))

program: $(SRC)
    qmake -project
    grep -qxF $(OPT) lessons.pro || echo $(OPT) >> lessons.pro
    mkdir -p  $(PRG)
    mv dersler.pro $(PRG)/$(PRG).pro
    cp $(SRC) $(PRG)/$(SRC)
    ( cd $(PRG) && qmake $(PRG).pro )
    ( cd $(PRG) && make )
    ( cd $(PRG) && mv lessons $(PRG))
```

When I try to compile, it makes 'hello' subdirectory and executable in that directory.

So far so good.

But when I add a second source file, let's say hello2.cc with the same content as of hello.cc, it doesn't work as expected.

It gives an error like this :

```
$ make
qmake -project
grep -qxF "QT += gui widgets" lessons.pro || echo "QT += gui widgets" >> lessons.pro
mkdir -p  hello2
mv lessons.pro hello2/hello2.pro
cp hello2.cc hello2/hello2.cc
( cd hello2 && qmake hello2.pro )
WARNING: Failure to find: hello.cc
WARNING: Failure to find: hello/hello.cc
WARNING: Failure to find: hello2/hello2.cc
( cd hello2 && make )
make[1]: Entering directory '/lessons/hello2'
Makefile:374: warning: overriding recipe for target 'hello.o'
Makefile:368: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'hello.o'
Makefile:377: warning: overriding recipe for target 'hello2.o'
Makefile:371: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'hello2.o'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'hello/hello.cc', needed by 'hello.o'. Durdu.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lessons/hello2'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'program' failed
```

Also there is not a file with *.o extension *'hello2.o'* in the second directory.

How should I fix this issue. If I add a new source file, it should be able to compile the last modified source file.

## Edit :

The issue is solved. The problem was since I was executing qmake from the top directory it was adding all files hello1.cc, hello2.cc as source.

This is solved simply by calling qmake from sub directory.

Comment: Analyze step by step each command executed by `make` and I guess You will find the reason. Please notice you are not copying hello.cc to hello2 directory which is required by `hello2.pro` to be visible in hello2 directory.

Comment: Ok after looking through source code of 'hello2.pro' in 'hello2' directory I recognised what the problem is. Project depends both 'hello1.cc' and 'hello2.cc'. Is there a way to run qmake with only one source file?

Comment: Your makefile in the top directory  builds a qmake project file based on the the sources present in that directory.  It then copies the project file to a different directory, with a different set of sources files, where, unsurprisingly, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a very strange way to be going about things, so I am inclined to believe that you've presented an X-Y problem.